# How can we increase the size of ephemeral storage in a kubernetes worker node

Tags: linux, kubernetes, kubeadm

We deploy a cluster with kubeadm (1 master 4 worker node).

```
$ kubectl describe node worker1

Name:               worker1
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=worker1
                    role=slave1
Annotations:        kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket: /var/run/dockershim.sock
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Tue, 24 Sep 2019 14:15:42 +0330
Taints:             node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule
Unschedulable:      false
Conditions:
  Type                 Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----                 ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  NetworkUnavailable   False   Tue, 24 Sep 2019 14:16:19 +0330   Tue, 24 Sep 2019 14:16:19 +0330   WeaveIsUp                    Weave pod has set this
  OutOfDisk            False   Mon, 07 Oct 2019 15:35:53 +0330   Sun, 06 Oct 2019 02:21:55 +0330   KubeletHasSufficientDisk     kubelet has sufficient disk space available
  MemoryPressure       False   Mon, 07 Oct 2019 15:35:53 +0330   Sun, 06 Oct 2019 02:21:55 +0330   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure         True    Mon, 07 Oct 2019 15:35:53 +0330   Mon, 07 Oct 2019 13:58:23 +0330   KubeletHasDiskPressure       kubelet has disk pressure
  PIDPressure          False   Mon, 07 Oct 2019 15:35:53 +0330   Tue, 24 Sep 2019 14:15:42 +0330   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready                True    Mon, 07 Oct 2019 15:35:53 +0330   Sun, 06 Oct 2019 02:21:55 +0330   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status. AppArmor enabled
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  192.168.88.206
  Hostname:    worker1
Capacity:
 attachable-volumes-azure-disk:  16
 cpu:                            4
 ephemeral-storage:              19525500Ki
 hugepages-1Gi:                  0
 hugepages-2Mi:                  0
 memory:                         16432464Ki
 pods:                           110
Allocatable:
 attachable-volumes-azure-disk:  16
 cpu:                            4
 ephemeral-storage:              17994700771
 hugepages-1Gi:                  0
 hugepages-2Mi:                  0
 memory:                         16330064Ki
 pods:                           110
System Info:
 Machine ID:                 2fc8f9eejgh5274kg1ab3f5b6570a8
 System UUID:                52454D5843-391B-5454-BC35-E0EC5454D19A
 Boot ID:                    5454514e-4e5f-4e46-af9b-2809f394e06f
 Kernel Version:             4.4.0-116-generic
 OS Image:                   Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
 Operating System:           linux
 Architecture:               amd64
 Container Runtime Version:  docker://17.3.2
 Kubelet Version:            v1.12.1
 Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.12.1
Non-terminated Pods:         (0 in total)
  Namespace                  Name    CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits
  ---------                  ----    ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource                       Requests  Limits
  --------                       --------  ------
  cpu                            0 (0%)    0 (0%)
  memory                         0 (0%)    0 (0%)
  attachable-volumes-azure-disk  0         0
Events:
  Type     Reason                Age                     From                 Message
  ----     ------                ----                    ----                 -------
  Normal   Starting              45m                     kube-proxy, worker1  Starting kube-proxy.
  Normal   Starting              23m                     kube-proxy, worker1  Starting kube-proxy.
  Warning  EvictionThresholdMet  2m29s (x502 over 5d5h)  kubelet, worker1     Attempting to reclaim ephemeral-storage
  Normal   Starting              75s                     kube-proxy, worker1  Starting kube-proxy.
```

As it can be seen from description of the worker1, there is a disk pressure(**ephemeral-storage:              19525500Ki**). We mount a hard disk to **/dev/sdb1**.

In worker1:

```
$ df -h`

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  163M  1.5G  11% /run
/dev/sda1        19G   16G  2.4G  87% /
tmpfs           7.9G  5.1M  7.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1        99G   61M   94G   1% /data
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1003
```

But the problem still exists. How can I tell the kubelet to add this mount point to the ephemeral-storage of the worker1? Actually, how can we increase the ephemeral storage of a node in a Kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of search, I decided to extend the size of **/sda1**. It is not pleasant to do that, but that is the only way I can find. Now the the ephemeral storage of the worker is increased.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  151M  1.5G  10% /run
/dev/sda1       118G   24G   89G  22% /
```

$ `kubectl describe node worker1`

```
attachable-volumes-azure-disk:  16
 cpu:                            4
 ephemeral-storage:              123729380Ki
 hugepages-1Gi:                  0
 hugepages-2Mi:                  0
 memory:                         16432464Ki
 pods:                           110
Allocatable:
 attachable-volumes-azure-disk:  16
 cpu:                            4
 ephemeral-storage:              114028996420
 hugepages-1Gi:                  0
 hugepages-2Mi:                  0
 memory:                         16330064Ki
 pods:                           110
```

Comment: According to this you will need to mount your disk to `/var/lib/kubelet`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70931881/what-does-kubelet-use-to-determine-the-ephemeral-storage-capacity-of-the-node or configure the path upon creation of the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, (AFAIK) the [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) which runs on your node doesn't really have a [SIGHUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) mechanism to hang up and pick a new configuration like other application like [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html). The short answer is that you are going to have to restart the kubelet. Typically:

```
$ systemctl restart kubelet
```

If you don't want your applications running there to be affected Kubernetes does have a mechanism: [drain](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/) and [cordon](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#manual-node-administration).

If you want to shutdown the pods yourself on the node and be careful about what gets shutdown at what time, etc, you can use cordon to prevent any workload being scheduled on that node:

```
$ kubectl cordon <nodename>
```

If you want Kubernetes to evict your pods on that node (together with making the non-schedulable with cordon):

```
$ kubectl drain <nodename>
```

One of the nice things about drain is that it supports the [PodDisruptionBudget](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/) resource, that allows you to safely drain pods without affecting uptime (Assuming that you have your pod disruption budgets defined appropriately)

Comment: I restart the kubelet in the worker1 and master node and it didn't work. Still the ephemeral storage is on 19525500Ki.

Comment: Did you increase the filesystem size? How did you increase the storage space originally?

Comment: I mount a external hard disk(/dev/sdb1 to the /data/ mount point.