# What does Kubelet use to determine the ephemeral-storage capacity of the node?

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

I have Kubernetes cluster running on a VM. A truncated overview of the mounts is:

```sh
$ df -h
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                      20G  4.5G   15G  24% /
/dev/mapper/vg001-lv--docker  140G   33G  108G  23% /var/lib/docker
```

As you can see, I added an extra disk to store the docker images and its volumes. However, when querying the node's capacity, the following is returned

```
Capacity:
  cpu:                12
  ephemeral-storage:  20145724Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             65831264Ki
  nvidia.com/gpu:     1
  pods:               110
```

`ephemeral-storage` is `20145724Ki` which is 20G, referring to the disk mounted at `/`.

How does Kubelet calculate its `ephemeral-storage`? Is it simply looking at the disk space available at `/`? Or is it looking at another folder like `/var/log/containers`?

[This is a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58269443/how-can-we-increase-the-size-of-ephemeral-storage-in-a-kubernetes-worker-node) where the user eventually succumbed to increasing the disk mounted at `/`.

Comment: Can you add more details about your Kubernetes cluster - version, how it's deployed?

Comment: It's on bare metal (VM actually) set up with kubeadm. Kubernetes version 1.18

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Some theory**

By default `Capacity` and `Allocatable` for ephemeral-storage in standard kubernetes environment is sourced from filesystem (mounted to /var/lib/kubelet).
This is the default location for kubelet directory.

[The kubelet supports the following filesystem partitions:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/node-pressure-eviction/#eviction-signals)

> 1. `nodefs`: The node's main filesystem, used for local disk volumes, emptyDir, log storage, and more. For example,  `nodefs`  contains
>    `/var/lib/kubelet/`.
> 2. `imagefs`: An optional filesystem that container runtimes use to store container images and container writable layers.
>
> Kubelet auto-discovers these filesystems and ignores other
> filesystems. Kubelet does not support other configurations.

From [Kubernetes website](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#resources) about volumes:

> The storage media (such as Disk or SSD) of an `emptyDir` volume is
> determined by the medium of the filesystem holding the kubelet root
> dir (typically `/var/lib/kubelet`).

Location for kubelet directory can be configured by providing:

1. [Command line parameter during kubelet initialization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/)

`--root-dir` string
Default: /var/lib/kubelet

2. Via [kubeadm with config file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/config-api/kubeadm-config.v1beta3/#kubeadm-init-configuration-types) (e.g.)

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
kind: InitConfiguration
nodeRegistration:
  kubeletExtraArgs:
    root-dir: "/data/var/lib/kubelet"
```

[Customizing kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/control-plane-flags/#customizing-the-kubelet):

> To customize the kubelet you can add a `KubeletConfiguration` next to
> the `ClusterConfiguration` or `InitConfiguration` separated by `---`
> within the same configuration file. This file can then be passed to
> `kubeadm init`.

When bootstrapping kubernetes cluster using kubeadm, `Capacity` reported by `kubectl get node` is equal to the disk capacity mounted into `/var/lib/kubelet`

However `Allocatable` will be reported as:
`Allocatable` = `Capacity` - `10% nodefs` using the standard kubeadm configuration, since [the kubelet has the following default hard eviction thresholds:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/node-pressure-eviction/#hard-eviction-thresholds)

- `nodefs.available<10%`

It can be configured during [kubelet initialization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) with:
`-eviction-hard` mapStringString
Default: imagefs.available<15%,memory.available<100Mi,nodefs.available<10%

---

**Example**

I set up a test environment for Kubernetes with a master node and two worker nodes (worker-1 and worker-2).

Both worker nodes have volumes of the same capacity: 50Gb.

Additionally, I mounted a second volume with a capacity of 20Gb  for the Worker-1 node at the path  `/var/lib/kubelet`.
Then I created a cluster with kubeadm.

**Result**

*From worker-1 node:*

```
skorkin@worker-1:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        49G  2.8G   46G   6% /
...
/dev/sdb         20G   45M   20G   1% /var/lib/kubelet
```

and

```
Capacity:
  cpu:                2
  ephemeral-storage:  20511312Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             4027428Ki
  pods:               110
```

Size of ephemeral-storage is the same as volume mounted at /var/lib/kubelet.

*From worker-2 node:*

```
skorkin@worker-2:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        49G  2.7G   46G   6% /
```

and

```
Capacity:
  cpu:                2
  ephemeral-storage:  50633164Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             4027420Ki
  pods:               110
```

Comment: Great answer! However, the ephemeral storage used when writing to the filesystem of a container (not EmptyDir), it ends up in `/var/lib/docker` (imagefs in the docs). I would have expected Kubernetes to monitor this path as wel?

Comment: So `root-dir` configures `nodefs` part, how do we configure `imagefs`?

Comment: @ShinebayarG  The container runtime filesystem contains both the read-only layer and the writeable layer. This is considered the `imagefs` in Kubernetes documentation.  https://kubernetes.io/blog/2024/01/23/kubernetes-separate-image-filesystem/#container-runtime